# Find the row and column of a range object

Tags: excel, vba

First I look to search for the range of a cell that corresponds to a value I want to find:

```
Dim a As Range
Set a = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("date", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Then what I'd like is something like:

```
a.row
a.Column
```

But there is a Compile error: method not valid without suitable object

Is there a way to find the row and column numbers of a range object that is obtained from searching for a cell value?

Comment: You need to check that a is not nothing before attempting to use its methods, as the Find may not actual return a valid range

Comment: And you cannot just write a.Row, you have to use an equation e.g. 'Dim b as Long' and 'b=a.Row' or 'MsgBox a.Row'

Answer (score 1):

## Range Compile Error

The compile error occurred because you cannot just write `a.Row` or `a.Column`, you have to use an equation or use it in a function. Find always returns either Nothing or a cell range which has its properties. When you have to use its row or column, then you write e.g.

```
Dim b as Long
b = a.Row
```

or to write to the same cell in another worksheet:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(a.Row, a.Column) = 25
```

To check if Find has found the value use the following code pattern.

### The Code

```
Sub CellRangeUsage

    Dim a As Range

    Set a = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("date", LookIn:=xlValues) 

    If Not a Is Nothing then ' Check if value was found.
        MsgBox "'date' was found in row " & a.Row & " of column " & a.Column & "."
      Else
        MsbBox "'date' was not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the debug.print or MsgBox function you can find out the row and column:

```
Sub findcell()

Dim a As Range
Set a = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("date", LookIn:=xlValues)

if Not(a is nothing) then
    Debug.Print "row of cell: " & a.Row
    Debug.Print "column of cell: " & a.Column
    MsgBox "row of cell: " & a.Row
    MsgBox "column of cell: " & a.Column
else: Msgbox "Cell not found"
end if

End Sub
```

Edit: I edited the code with a if-branch, considering what Harassed mentioned

Comment: Don't forget to take on board Harassed Dad's comment.